# Making a online log

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, blogs

I just leased a domain name and some server space. I'm learning ruby on rails and I took the domain so that I can put my projects online.

However, there is still some time left to go for a good project on rails to be completed. In the meantime I want to document my daily progress, as in what all new did I learn about web development on a given day.

I would want to host online (on that same domain) a temporary log so that I can log what I'm doing. I can use Wordpress or some other popular blogging platform but I would really want to put use something which I can make and learn in the process.

Is there a publishing platform out there which just provides a base you can build on? preferably in RoR or php? I would really want to learn from this exercise so if anyone has any suggestions or any resources to point it, I'll be really grateful.

Thanks

Comment: a Shoutbox may be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you build your own small blog? Have a look at this: [create a blog from scratch using RoR](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-blog-from-scratch-using-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: +1, this is a good functional "hello world" project for a web framework.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [arailsdemo](http://arailsdemo.com) which will teach you to build a blog and get it online in under a few hours - it's quite easy

Answer (score 0):

Why not install wordpress which will supply you with a good starting point. And build a theme and plugins over it using their API.

The [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is a starting point, but there are plenty of other resources on the net.